# WARNING, Unable to connect to cloud code on https

Tags: express, parse-platform, parse-server

After setting up parse on https I receive this message .

```
'WARNING, Unable to connect to https://localhost:2096/parse'. 
Cloud code and push notifications may be unavailable!
```

here is my configuration :

```
serverURL: 'https://localhost:2096/parse',
publicServerURL: 'https://core.com:2096/parse',

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var port = 2096;
var httpsServer = require('https').createServer(credentials, app);
```

any idea how to make it work ?

Regards

Comment: Can you please add here the complete code of your server initialization and  the complete stack trace of the error you have?

Comment: https://www.pastiebin.com/5a22975797976 here is it @DaviMacêdo
the error is up there, the warning

Comment: Is the same code working when running on http? Who is throwing the error? Is you client code? Can you please also send the code the is throwing this error?

Comment: I just set https and npm start... if it's http it will work but if it's https it shows me this message, should I make a screenshot ?